# Find an equation of the plane containing $(1,2,−3)$, $(0,1,−2)$ and $(1,2,−2)$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vectors

> Find an equation of the plane containing $(1,2,−3)$, $(0,1,−2)$ and $(1,2,−2)$

I tried solving this way:

$A= (1,2,-3)$

$B= (0,1,-2)$

$C= (1,2,-2)$

$\overrightarrow{AB} = \langle 0-1, 1-2, -2-3 \rangle = \langle -1, -1, -5 \rangle$

$\overrightarrow{AC} = \langle 1-1, 2-2, -2-3 \rangle = \langle 0, 0, -5 \rangle$

$\overrightarrow{AB} - \overrightarrow{AC} = \langle -1, -1, 0 \rangle$

And then I set up the equation this way:

$-(x-1)-(y-2)=0$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: What does $\overrightarrow{AB} - \overrightarrow{AC}$ have to do in this question?

Comment: @Bernard I thought that was wrong too, but I wasn't sure what step to take next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

A vector normal to the plane is $\overrightarrow{AB}\wedge \overrightarrow{AC}=(5,-5,0)$. You may as well take $\vec n=(1,-1,0)$.

Once you have a normal vector, and a point, say $A$, the equation is simply ($O$ denotes the origin, as you might suspect):
$$\vec n\cdot \overrightarrow{OM}=\vec n\cdot \overrightarrow{OA}$$

Comment: So the vectors $(5,-5,0)$ and $(1,-1,0)$ are acceptable since the first is just a scalar multiple of the second making them on the same plane?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why my book uses $(1,-1,0)$

Comment: For the first question: yes they're both acceptable. Anyw two normal vectors are colinear. Second comment: I suppose for the same reason as me: it simplifies computations.

Answer (score 0):

Equation of a plane is A(x-x1) + B(y-y1) + C(z-z1) = 0

1) Now given 3 points you want to find v1 and v2 by subtracting any of your points.

2) Then you would cross product them as in V1XV2.

3) The coefficients of the resulting vector will be used as A,B,C in your formula so you can replace that there and choose one of your points for your (x1,y1,z1) and that should set up your equation.